# How to log the time that events occur natively in Firebug?

Tags: php, ajax, firebug

I'm trying to debug a faulty Ajax call from a PHP web app. To do that I'm using Firebug to track every time the script is called.

In the console I see the GET calls to the script, but to accumulate this many can take some minutes and is not practical to time it by hand.

[image]

My question is : ***How can I log the time each GET call occurs natively from Firebug?***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to use [`console.timeStamp()`](https://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/Console.timeStamp) within your script. This prints a time stamp along with an arbitrary string to the [console](https://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/Console_Panel) and creates a marker line within the [*Net* panel](https://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/Net_Panel).